# How do I set up the Windows 10 "Your Phone" App's Calls feature?

Tags: windows-10, android, your-phone

I've got the Windows 10 "Your Phone" app set up, except for the "Calls" feature, which allows you to receive phone calls using your PC's audio.  It keeps prompting me to pair my phone and my PC over Bluetooth, even though they're already paired. All the notifications pop up, such as the one asking for permission to make my phone discoverable over bluetooth, but after the pairing succeeds, the setup still fails with the message "We couldn't finish connecting. Wait a bit, then try again".

My only clue to what is going on is that when I open Bluetooth on my phone, and tap on my computer to connect to it, it says "Connection failed", and when I open my Windows 10 notifications and click "Connect", my phone doesn't appear in the list.

After unpairing, re-pairing, uninstalling the Your phone app from my PC and phone, then reinstalling, I'm stumped. Do I need a new bluetooth dongle? I'm currently using a [TECHKEY usb dongle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07J5WFPXX), which works fine for bluetooth headphones and game controllers.

Answer (score 0):

the following guide may help you:
1. Swiping downwards from the top of your screen to reveal the Android Notification panel. Tap and hold the Bluetooth icon.
2. A list of nearby devices will be displayed. Locate the name of your PC in this list and tap on it.
3. You should see notifications on both your Android phone and Windows 10 PC. Tap or click on these toasts to confirm.
4. The connection process should now be complete, and you’ll be able to use the Calls feature.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4531607/troubleshooting-calls

Comment: The toasts appear, I click on all of them, and the PC appears in the list of paired devices, but not the list of connected devices.  The setup then asks me to pair again, and the process repeats.